# HttpListenerResponse - behavior when throwing HttpListenerException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, internet-explorer-9

people,

I created a small webserver for a custom application. The webserver works fine, yet from time to time it throws some exceptions, when I try to send a response to the client using HttpListenerResponse. Assume I have

```
HttpListenerResponse res = ctx.Response; // My HttpListenerContext
... //initialize the response
res.StatusCode = 200;
try
   {
        res.OutputStream.Write(terminate, 0, terminate.Length);
        res.Close();
   }
catch(HttpListenerException hex){ ... }
```

Now, it happens that the connection breaks down (I get Windows System Error-Codes 22, 64, 1229)
[MSDN-reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382.aspx). My client is the WPF-Webbrowser-control.
What does the client receive? Does the client receive the HTTP 200? Or can I alter the status-code inside the exception and somehow push it to the client?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The client isn't going to receive anything unless you somehow retry after handling the exception. The client will eventually time out.

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you for your reply, Jim. When I receive the errors 64 and 1229 they say, that the connection broke. I guess I am not able to open a Connection to the client...?